# How to get blog name, when using Wordpress Multisite

Tags: multisite

I have a wordpress multisite installtion with 5 sites within, the multisite is called **Lifestyle**

1. Homes
2. Cars
3. Architecture
4. Holidays
5. Communities

I am trying to get the **blog** name, for each blog when viewing in my theme, every function I use returns 'Lifestyle'.

I have tried;

```
get_bloginfo('name');

get_bloginfo();

global $current_site; var_dump(get_current_site_name($current_site));

get_current_blog();
```

none of the strings or objects returned contain the blog name, they all contain the site name "Lifestyle" can anyone offer any advice...

Comment: http://www.social-ink.net/blog/wp_get_multisites-wordpress3-wp3-generating-dynamic-list-of-multisites-or-replacing-get_blog_list this looks interesting.... anything you can work with?  Wait, I might be misunderstanding.... you are trying to list each site ON said site, or sites on the main site?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
global $blog_id;
$current_blog_details = get_blog_details( array( 'blog_id' => $blog_id ) );
echo $current_blog_details->blogname;
```

Have a nice multisite! :)

Comment: 'name' - Returns the "Site Title" set in Settings > General. This data is retrieved from the "blogname" record in the wp_options table.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo

Comment: You can directly get current blog name by `get_blog_details()->blogname` as default it will take current blog ID.  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_blog_details/